# Markers are not drawn instantaniously when enter the mapview, and sometimes they should show up in the mapview but they don't

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I came across some problems regarding the drawing of markers on the mapview in my app and decided to create a test

```
package com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp.activity.annotation;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.TypeEvaluator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapboxAccountManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerViewOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.ILatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Projection;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class AnimatedMarkerActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MarkerView dMarker;
    private MarkerView[] dMarkers;
    private boolean mIsDragged = false;
    private float mDx;
    private float mDy;
    private ArrayList draggableMarkerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.

        // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the account manager
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_annotation_animated_marker);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap)
            {
                dMarkers = new MarkerView[10];
                draggableMarkerList = new ArrayList();

                for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    dMarkers[i] = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(51.502615, 4.972326+(i*0.01))));
                    draggableMarkerList.add(dMarkers[i]);
                }

                mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                    {
                        boolean dragged = false;
                        for(int i=0; i<draggableMarkerList.size(); i++)
                        {
                            dragged = drag(mapboxMap, i, v, event);
                        }

                        return dragged;
                    }
                });

//                mapboxMap.setOnMapClickListener(new         MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
//
//                        // When the user clicks on the map, we want to  animate the marker to that
//                        // location.
//                        ValueAnimator markerAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(dMarker, "position",
//                                new LatLngEvaluator(), dMarker.getPosition(), point);
//                        markerAnimator.setDuration(2000);
//                        markerAnimator.start();
//                    }
//                });

            }
        });
    }

private boolean drag(MapboxMap mapviewMap, int i, View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    final int action = event.getActionMasked();
    dMarker = (MarkerView) draggableMarkerList.get(i);
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        Projection projection = mapviewMap.getProjection();
        // TODO: 08/04/2016 extend the area of movement in the getdrawingbounds()
        Bitmap drawable = dMarker.getIcon().getBitmap();
        float halfWidth = drawable.getWidth()/2;
        PointF markerPosPx = projection.toScreenLocation(dMarker.getPosition());
        RectF boundRect = new RectF(markerPosPx.x-halfWidth,
                markerPosPx.y-halfWidth,
                markerPosPx.x+halfWidth,
                markerPosPx.y+halfWidth);

        float dp = 25;
        Resources resources = Resources.getSystem();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);

        boundRect.left = boundRect.left - px;
        boundRect.right = boundRect.right + px;
        boundRect.top = boundRect.top - px;
        boundRect.bottom = boundRect.bottom + px;

        if(boundRect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()))
        {
            mIsDragged = true;
            //markerPosPx is current position of marker in pixels
            mDx = markerPosPx.x - event.getX();
            mDy = markerPosPx.y - event.getY();
        }
    }
    if(mIsDragged)
    {
        if((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))
        {
            mIsDragged = false;
        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            Projection pj = mapviewMap.getProjection();
            ILatLng pos;

            pos = pj.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(event.getX() + mDx, event.getY() + mDy));

            LatLng position = new LatLng(pos.getLatitude(), pos.getLongitude());
            dMarker.setPosition(position);

            for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                dMarkers[j].setPosition(new LatLng(pos.getLatitude(), pos.getLongitude()+(j*0.01)));
            }
            Log.d("", Double.valueOf(pos.getLatitude()).toString());
        }
    }

    return mIsDragged;
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private static class LatLngEvaluator implements TypeEvaluator<LatLng> {
    // Method is used to interpolate the marker animation.

    private LatLng latLng = new LatLng();

    @Override    
    public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng     endValue) {
        latLng.setLatitude(startValue.getLatitude()
                + ((endValue.getLatitude() - startValue.getLatitude()) *     fraction));
        latLng.setLongitude(startValue.getLongitude()
                + ((endValue.getLongitude() - startValue.getLongitude()) *    fraction));
        return latLng;
    }
    }
    }

}
```

You can find the gif for the demo of this code on the following LINK

I have drawn 10 markers, all of them at a longitude distance of 0.01, whenever one marker is dragged, positions on all of them are changed, If we move the camera around, we can observe that while they are getting back in the mapview, they are not drawn instantaniously, rather they take a slight moment, and sometimes they disapear for a moment, during the test i also found out that if some of the markers go out of the mapview and then position on them is changed, then they don't show up in mapview even though their new position is within the shown screen bounds.

I have opened a ticket explaining my problem that i have not been able to figure out yet, but i strongly suspect that the issues unearthened during this test are linked to my issue (flickering of markers upon setting new positions on them)

Comment: LINK for the ticket: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7352

Comment: Have you tried switching to MarkerView? I have noticed issues when dynamically changing positions of markers.